# Can I add package libasound2 to the NixOS repository?

Tags: nixos

Attempting to build my project, I find that I am missing the library `asound`.

My issue matches the one at [this](http://haskell-art.lurk.narkive.com/3fx1GBTx/asound-not-found-during-euterpea-installation) thread, where the issue was solved by installing the debian package `libasound2` listed [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libasound2).

I am running `NixOS` and do not see the `libasound2` package available for install via `nix-env`.

Is there some other way that I can install the dependency? Can it be added to the NixOS package list? If so, how do I go about doing that?

---

My project build uses Haskell's `stack`, and the command `$ stack build`. Full output is shown below.

```
$ stack build
PortMidi-0.1.5.2: configure
Progress: 1/3
--  While building package PortMidi-0.1.5.2 using:
      /home/matthew/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/nix/store/vs9mh0q32flklzi8hl0ksr9d3jv21399-ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/nix/store/vs9mh0q32flklzi8hl0ksr9d3jv21399-ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/matthew/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/pkgdb --package-db=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/doc/PortMidi-0.1.5.2 --htmldir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/doc/PortMidi-0.1.5.2 --haddockdir=/home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-9.11/8.0.2/doc/PortMidi-0.1.5.2 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/83413105lyc3n8pbmi2qbz3f82x06sp1-postgresql-9.5.7/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/9csmflf5p58jf3h2i36x0p5b5cw3aijf-git-2.14.1/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/clvw27qshazq458waarrjqj0k5qpnjkn-pkg-config-0.29/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/ff6n25jbkj71kr5sbazgwa9zlngyllx7-pcre-8.40-dev/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/kpa2p2p0m4xys9wdm735nw9xi4d3n5gr-zlib-1.2.11-dev/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/px00dygm925m7caqwnm76xi46m2rcx4p-binutils-2.27-dev/include --extra-include-dirs=/nix/store/vs9mh0q32flklzi8hl0ksr9d3jv21399-ghc-8.0.2/include --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/681f2q7npfgr6394dg3yqc7mh0n2wns9-binutils-2.27-lib/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/9csmflf5p58jf3h2i36x0p5b5cw3aijf-git-2.14.1/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/clvw27qshazq458waarrjqj0k5qpnjkn-pkg-config-0.29/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/fwxgxaclys016hlvk68lbl0ipx5nc95l-pcre-8.40/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/hzl3zrsfw4wf0cwk1qw61a4k1c9b2667-postgresql-9.5.7-lib/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/sg6ri2jj92sbv7f4rvchzr00d24pi4nq-zlib-1.2.11/lib --extra-lib-dirs=/nix/store/vs9mh0q32flklzi8hl0ksr9d3jv21399-ghc-8.0.2/lib
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/matthew/backup/perfectpitch/perfectpitch/.stack-work/logs/PortMidi-0.1.5.2.log

    Configuring PortMidi-0.1.5.2...
    Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing C library: asound
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

---

It was suggested in the comments that I install `alsaLib`.
I attempted this using `nix-env` by running the command `$ nix-env -iA nixos.alsaLib`. This attempt did not work (I ran into the same `* Missing C library: asound` error when trying to build following this `nix-env` install).

Comment: Try the `alsaLib` NixOS package.

Comment: @ppb somehow I still get the same `Missing C library: asound` error after installing `alsaLib`

Comment: You are welcome to submitting a pull request to [nixpkgs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs). Please give it a try.

Comment: @mherzl how exactly are you building the package and installing the library? Under Nix / NixOS the compilers / build tools won't be able to see packages installed via `nix-env` or global configuration. Typically you would write a nix expression to build your project and list `alsaLib` in its build inputs.

Comment: @ppb I placed `  packages: [alsaLib]` under `nix:` in my `stack.yaml` file and that worked to get me past this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the project to build by placing the following into `stack.yaml`.

```
nix:
  packages: [alsaLib]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's now called alsa-lib

https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&show=alsa-lib&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=alsa-lib